# Functional Component or Class Component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-component

After React 16.8 React Hook provides us handling state in functional component. Now which is the recommended component to use in React App?

Comment: Dan Abramov's tweet =) https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/1118107150918746112

Answer (score 1):

With hooks it's preferred to use functional components. This is what they mention on their official page -

> **Classes confuse both people and machines**
>   In addition to making code reuse and code organization more difficult, we’ve found that classes can be a large barrier to learning React. You have to understand how this works in JavaScript, which is very different from how it works in most languages. You have to remember to bind the event handlers. Without unstable syntax proposals, the code is very verbose. People can understand props, state, and top-down data flow perfectly well but still struggle with classes. The distinction between function and class components in React and when to use each one leads to disagreements even between experienced React developers.
>
> Additionally, React has been out for about five years, and we want to
>   make sure it stays relevant in the next five years. As Svelte,
>   Angular, Glimmer, and others show, ahead-of-time compilation of
>   components has a lot of future potential. Especially if it’s not
>   limited to templates. Recently, we’ve been experimenting with
>   component folding using Prepack, and we’ve seen promising early
>   results. However, we found that class components can encourage
>   unintentional patterns that make these optimizations fall back to a
>   slower path. Classes present issues for today’s tools, too. For
>   example, classes don’t minify very well, and they make hot reloading
>   flaky and unreliable. We want to present an API that makes it more
>   likely for code to stay on the optimizable path.
>
> **To solve these problems**, **Hooks let you use more of React’s features
>   without classes**. Conceptually, React components have always been
>   closer to functions. Hooks embrace functions, but without sacrificing
>   the practical spirit of React. Hooks provide access to imperative
>   escape hatches and don’t require you to learn complex functional or
>   reactive programming techniques.

To read more about it - https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Answer (score 0):

With hooks all of the components are functional components, but there are similarities. For example;

1. If you are using **useEffect hook** it acts like a lifecycle method, you listen the prop changes and trigger some functions accordingly. But *it is still a functional component*, it does not extend class React.Component
2. If you are using **useState hook** you hold a state in your component but again *it is a functional component* that does not extend class React.Component
3. If you are using no hooks, ie just getting props and showing the related data, again *it is a functional component*, you are just not using any hooks

Answer (score 0):

It's up to you, I'd do whatever works best for your team. My team is used to object oriented languages such as java and c# so we stick with classes as they are easier to understand for people new to javascript.

[There are no plans to remove react classes](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html), so there is no need to future proof your code by switching to functions.